# DLE вывод кастомной переменной

Tags: php, cms, dle

Вещь вроде как очевидная, но не выходит, кто бы пнул в какую сторону копать.

Суть в следующем, следуя руководству DLE в папке modules создал php файл, допустим test.php, и в одном из темплейтов добавил этот модуль -

```
{include file="engine/modules/test.php"}
```

в браузере вывод из модуля отображается, пока все хорошо и замечательно.

Следуя логике разделения логики от отображения, хотелось бы определить в модуле несколько плэйсхолдеров, которые можно было распечатать в темплейте. Судя по нескольким примерам и аналогией со Smarty, в модели должно работать нечто похожее на:

```
$tpl->set( '{test-test}', 'test-test-test' );
```

с последующей распечаткой этого в шаблоне как

```
{test-test}
```

Но почему-то это не работает. Был бы премного благодарен совету

Answer (score 4):

НАЙДИТЕ

```
$tpl->set ( '{AJAX}', $ajax );
$tpl->set ( '{headers}', $metatags."\n".build_js($js_array, $config) );
```

После вставте

```
$tpl->set ( '{test-test}', 'test-test-test' );
```

Вроде так должно работать. Удачи!

Comment: Да, вы правы, так работает, видимо я чего-то не догоняю - переменные могут определяться только в index? В принципе это подходит для статических данных, но идея была в определении значения этих переменных в моделях, что позволило им быть динамическими. Думаю я что-то упустил, и доступ к переменным должен где-то быть.

Comment: Я с ДЛЕ работал более 5 лет назад. Когда еще была версия 6.2-7.0. 
Переменные определяются не только в индексах, а еще в модулях, точнее сказать не могу, так как не помню, да и уже поменялось все. Вы хотите модуль запихнуть в тегу?. Можете через буфер инклудить файлы и после вывести, также можете и без буфера. Если Вам надо много тег к определенному tpl файлу. Надо искать, в каком-то файле там практически все теги

Comment: В engine.php идет перечисление модулей switch - case'ом. Как только вы добавите свой модуль, то по адресу site.ru/?do=mymodule будет доступен ваш модуль. Там подключите класс для работы с БД и шаблонами. Как пример советую смотреть самый простой модуль feedback.php. Сам недавно делал для себя модуль и делал по правилам DLE

Comment: подключение модулей это ясно, просто с передачей данных в темплейты, к примеру у меня в темлейте есть форма с элементами select, я хотел в модуле, вытащить массив данных, собрать из него выпадающий список и передать его в темплейт как, допустим как это пишут в руководстве, $tpl->set('{list-types}', $list-data). В темплейте было бы нечто похожее на <select name="types">{list-types}</select>.
В итоге на данный момент единственным решением оказалось перенести весь html код формы в файл модели и оттуда возвращать это все в темплейт